# Removing odd characters in R with gsub

Tags: r, gsub

I am currently in the process of doing some text analysis. I want to keep only alphanumeric characters but for some reason I am having trouble removing some pesky characters that I don't consider alphanumeric. Here's an example of what I am dealing with:

```
letters <- "ՄĄՄdasdas"
letters <- gsub("[^[:alnum:]]", "",letters)   
letters

> "ՄĄՄdasdas"
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: On my system, `gsub("[^[:alnum:]]", "", letters)` returns `"Adasdas"`. R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10) Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit); locale English_Australia.1252

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@konvas shows you how to use `gsub` correctly in this situation. The problem with your attempt is that those non-ASCII characters are considered alphabetic characters in your locale. Another option is to use `iconv`:

```
iconv(letters, to='ASCII', sub='')
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `gsub("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "", letters)`